# Caching problem for html and js file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cache, knockoutjs

I am working on **Magento 2 knockout js**. But when I am changing **HTML or js** file it's not effecting on frontend I run all this command

**setup:upgrade, static:content:deploy, di:compile, cace:flush**

But **sometimes these files changed and sometimes not changed.**

Anyone guide me how can we resolve this type of issue in Magento 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to clear Browser Cache or Disable it when developing.

One more tip: to make sure our Js or HTML static files change or not. Search them on Network tab (Chrome Browser), open in new tab and check it.

[image]

Comment: This is very useful trick. We need not clear all browser cache for just one file change. If we open a file in the new tab and file not changed than just refresh new tab to see changes. I do this same all the time when working with HTML and js changes.

Comment: You can try this with ctrl+f5 in chrome sometimes x3  All browser have short to refresh with cleaning cache

Answer (score 0):

When you have done any changes into **Knockout file, html file or any js file** it will not affect directly because when we deploy content data **it will create cache data into `pub/static` folder** after that each time magento retrieve data from pub. So whenever you apply any changes you have to apply

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

if changes not applied even though you have to delete pub/static folder manually or apply command `rm -rf pub/static`

No need to apply `php bin/magento cache:flush/clean' or php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to revolve your issue (make sure you're in **developer** mode):

1. Use command combination: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento static:content:deploy`. `setup:upgrade` will clean all generated code, static content and var/view_preprocessed.
2. You can delete the static file in `pub/static`. Magento will auto create symlink to that file on the flight at the next request. After that you can edit main file and no need to care about static file.